# Bash script file read, bash deletes spaces

Tags: string, bash, file

This questions is a follow up to my previous question about reading certain lines of a file.
I read my file as follows:

```
while read line 
do
    if [ "$line" == "SUMMARY OF POLARIZATION CALCULATION" ]; then
        for i in {1..9}
        do
            read line
            echo $line >> ../../Summary.out
        done
        break
    fi
done < ../Tutorial1_1.out
```

Which looks like this:

```
.
.
.
 O  (0.0000, 0.5000, 0.4834)  sp(1)  6.00 [ 0.000000e+00,  1.884956e+01,  1.822516e+01]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total ionic phase (rad)       sp(1)       [ 7.539822e+01,  7.539822e+01,  1.119960e+02]
Total ionic phase wrap. (rad) sp(1)       [ 8.633172e-11,  8.633172e-11, -1.101384e+00]
Ionic polarization (C/m2)     sp(1)       [ 1.365657e-11,  1.365657e-11, -1.760570e-01]
=======================================================================================

SUMMARY OF POLARIZATION CALCULATION
=======================================================================================
Value                           |  spin   |    dir(1)    |    dir(2)    |    dir(3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Electronic polarization (C/m2)     sp(1)  [-8.783054e-12, -8.828765e-13,  4.803326e-01]
Ionic polarization (C/m2)          sp(1)  [ 1.365657e-11,  1.365657e-11, -1.760570e-01]
Tot. spin polariz.=Pion+Pel (C/m2) sp(1)  [ 4.873517e-12,  1.277369e-11,  3.042756e-01]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL POLARIZATION (C/m2)          both   [ 4.873517e-12,  1.277369e-11,  3.042756e-01]
=======================================================================================

Completed using BerryPI version: +++Version 1.2 (Mar 12, 2014)
...
```

So the code above just take the 9 lines after the "SUMMARY.." and writes to Summary.out file. However, when it writes it screws up all the spacing, so i get the following:

```
=======================================================================================
Value | spin | dir(1) | dir(2) | dir(3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Electronic polarization (C/m2) sp(1) [-8.783054e-12, -8.828765e-13, 4.803326e-01]
Ionic polarization (C/m2) sp(1) [ 1.365657e-11, 1.365657e-11, -1.760570e-01]
Tot. spin polariz.=Pion+Pel (C/m2) sp(1) [ 4.873517e-12, 1.277369e-11, 3.042756e-01]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL POLARIZATION (C/m2) both [ 4.873517e-12, 1.277369e-11, 3.042756e-01]
=======================================================================================
```

How can i fix that, is there a flag that would read and write a string exactly as it is in the input file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to use

```
echo "$line" >> ../../Summary.out
```

instead of

```
echo $line >> ../../Summary.out
```

Comment: Tell me if i'm understanding this right. Without the "" the string variable is treated like an array where only the none empty elements are printed, while with "" it treats it as a string?

Comment: Better not to think of it as an array (since `bash` also has arrays). Instead, think of `$line` as a macro. The string `$line` is replaced by the contents of the variable `line`, and just like `echo a    b` will simply print `a b` (multiple spaces replaced by one space), so to `echo $line` will treat any runs of whitespace in `$line` as simple field separators, and each field is printed with one space between.

Comment: However, to preserve leading and trailing whitespace as well, you'll need to use `IFS= read` instead of just `read`, as well as quoting the expansion of `$line`.

Comment: The difference there is how shell will pass arguments to `echo` command. When you don't use quotes around `$line`, this variable will be evaluated and result will be passed to `echo` as one or more arguments. When you quote variable it will evaluated and result will be passed to `echo` as single argument. So, when you execute `$line = 'a b c'; echo $line` echo command will get 3 arguments. But if you will add quote around `$line` then echo will get only one argument (and spaces will be preserved).